# SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value when selecting two tables

Tags: t-sql, subquery

I tried to get a result from two tables to get names based on ID

But I do that I get the following messages : SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value

Here the two tables

```
TIME_TABLE

ACTIVITY_ID     ID_TIME     CREATED_BY_ID       MODIFIED_BY_ID
XF34            145         US1                 US5
XF56            146         US4                 US2
XF65            147         US4                 US5
XF76            148         US3                 US3


USER_TABLE

ID_USER     NAME
US1         JOHN        
US2         ALEX
US3         NOE
US4         GREG
US5         FRED
```

And here the result I tried to get.

```
RESULT

ACTIVITY_ID     ID_TIME     CREATED_BY_ID       MODIFIED_BY_ID
XF34            145         JOHN                FRED
XF56            146         GREG                ALEX
XF65            147         GREG                FRED
XF76            148         NOE                 NOE
```

Here my Query

```
SELECT
ACTIVITY_ID,
ID_TIME,
(SELECT T1.NAME FROM USER_TABLE T1 LEFT JOIN TIME_TABLE T2 ON T1.ID_USER = T2.CREATED_BY_ID) AS CREATED_BY,
(SELECT T1.NAME FROM USER_TABLE T1 LEFT JOIN TIME_TABLE T2 ON T1.ID_USER = T2.MODIFIED_BY_ID) AS MODIFIED BY
FROM TIME_TABLE
```

I can't find where I'm wrong with my request.

Could you help me please ?

Comment: If you want to use sub query then it should be `(SELECT U.NAME FROM USER_TABLE U U.ID_USER = TIME_TABLE.CREATED_BY_ID) AS CREATED_BY`. Assuming that `ID_USER`  is the primary key column in `USER_TABLE`

Answer (score 0):

OK found the solution. I need to put the join after and not in a subquery.
Like this

```
SELECT
T1.ACTIVITY_ID,
T1.ID_TIME,
T2.NAME AS CREATED_BY,
T3.NAME AS MODIFIED_BY
FROM TIME_TABLE T1
LEFT JOIN USER_TABLE T2 ON T2.ID_USER = T1.CREATED_BY_ID
LEFT JOIN USER_TABLE T3 ON T3.ID_USER = T1.MODIFIED_BY_ID
```